# How to finish() two activities at the same time?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, stack

I am writing a math app for little kids to learn maths. It first prompts the user to select what kind of questions they want (`MainActivity`), and then it shows a bunch of questions (`QuestionsActivity`). After answering 10 questions, it tells you which question(s) did you answer correctly and which you didn't (ResultsActivity).

I know that Android puts all the activities on a stack. In my case, it would look like this:

```
ResultsActivity
QuestionsActivity
MainActivity
```

And when you call `finish`, an activity is popped from the stack. I want there to be a back to main menu button in the `ResultsActivity` to go back to the `MainActivity`. However, if I call `finish` in the `ResultsActivity`, the user would see `QuestionsActivity`! So how am I going to call `finish` on the both activities?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two options:

1. Call `finish()` in QuestionsActivity after you make the call to start the ResultsActivity. This will remove it from the stack so that pressing back from ResultsActivity returns to MainActivity.
2. Use [`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) in the intent to go back to MainActivity. This will clear all activities that are on top of it.

Answer (score 6):

You can clear your stack by simple starting your MainActivity again and clearing the stack with the following flags:

```
  final Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) instead of starting a new task as it's more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, that is nice to know. :)

Comment: But if the user presses the back button in ResultsActivity it would still go back to QuestionsActivity, right?

Comment: Override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) to start the `MainActivity` instead with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag set.